# Convert Multiline into list

Tags: python, list

I have extracted a set of data from HTML page and copied to a variable. The variable looks like

```
names='''
      Apple
      Ball
      Cat'''
```

Now I like to join each line into a list so that I  can access any line I want. Is there any way to do that in Python

Answer (score 21):

Using splitlines() to split by newline character and strip() to remove unnecessary white spaces.

```
>>> names='''
...       Apple
...       Ball
...       Cat'''
>>> names
'\n      Apple\n      Ball\n      Cat'
>>> names_list = [y for y in (x.strip() for x in names.splitlines()) if y]
>>> # if x.strip() is used to remove empty lines
>>> names_list
['Apple', 'Ball', 'Cat']
```

Comment: note: this will not split by lines properly if any line has a space (or other whitespace character) in it

Comment: I am using python 2.6.6 and it worked fine in that. It would be helpful if you can give me an example.

Comment: @wim +1 I agree-- by default `split` will use whitespace as the delimiter. @topcoder: try putting putting an entry with a space or tab in it in the first line.

Comment: Thanks @agf. I forgot that completely.

Comment: `names_list = [x for x in (y.split() for y in names.splitlines()) if x]` is how you call `split` once :-)

Comment: aaaah. Thanks :). One more level of indirection. :)

Comment: and by `split` i mean `strip` ofc :-/

Comment: I actually prefer the earlier revision which calls split twice, it's more readable and I doubt this is performance-critical code that needs micro-optimisations.

Answer (score 16):

`names.splitlines()` should give you just that.

Comment: If there are really spaces on every line, and a blank first line, there is still post-processing to do.

Comment: True.  I don't know whether or not that is _ignorable_ whitespace for the OP's use case though.

Answer (score -1):

`names.split('\n')` should give you a list split by '\n'

Comment: The weakness is that his platform might have a more complicated line ending than just `'\n'`.