# String Manipulation in python, different length

Tags: python, string, list, string-length

I have a string like below:

```
string A:     animals_goat=1; country=3 4 5; Foo=1 2 3;
string 1:     country=0 1 2; Foo=0 0 0;
string 2:     country=0 0 0; Foo=1 1 1;
```

I want to compare the strings which are of different length and need output like below:

```
animals_goat=1; country=0 1 2; Foo=0 0 0; 
animals_goat=1; country=0 0 0; Foo=1 1 1;
```

Note:

1. I am reading string1 and string 2 and compare it with string A and print out the string like I have done.  String A is like master string with all the values. Currently I have string A in a variable and string1 and string 2 in another variable.
2. When going through the longest string, compare it to the shortest string when an element match, I want the matching element in the longest string to be replaced  with the same element in the shortest string in this case, country=0 1 2, where country matched in both the strings and it prints the second string value
3. Then it prints the next element in the longest string since there is no match
4. Also all the elements in the short string ARE ALWAYS present in the long string.

I tried to put the variable and value into two separate lists for both the strings but cant get it to iterate through all the 4 lists at the same time. IS there a way to do this??

The answer provided works except that my string 1 and string 2 are contained ina  signle variable as a multiline string.

```
string= animals_goat=1; country=0 1 2; Foo=0 0 0;
        animals_goat=1; country=0 0 0; Foo=1 1 1;
```

so when I do "for line in string:" it gave me an error. I am now trying to convert it into:

```
['animals_goat=1; country=0 1 2; Foo=0 0 0;','animals_goat=1; country=0 0 0; Foo=1 1 1;']
```

However when I do

```
string_list = [y for y in (x.strip() for x in string.splitlines()) if y]  

I end up with below: 

['animals_goat=1;'' country=0 1 2;''Foo=0 0 0;']
['animals_goat=1;'' country=0 0 0;''Foo=0 0 0;']
```

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are asking, where are the 4 lists?

Comment: If the list of 4 items are clarification/specs to your question, you might not want it to be in code format but just be plain-text.

Comment: I did stringA.split("=|;") and that gives two lists one with variables and the other with the values. So I have 6 lists. ex: ['animals_goat','country','Foo'] and ['1','3 4 5','1 2 3'] so on for the other two strings. But I still cant get the output I want. I tried using itertools,zip ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize, we have master data that needs to be updated for each line that we process.  The approach here is to parse the master data into a list of items that can be easily converted to a dictionary.  Then, taking one line at a time, we create that dictionary and update it with the parsed values from the line.  The results are then printed.

As per the updated question, I now have the `lines` variable consists of a single string of several newline-separated lines:

```
# Input data
master = 'animals_goat=1; country=3 4 5; Foo=1 2 3;'
lines = """country=0 1 2; Foo=0 0 0;
country=0 0 0; Foo=1 1 1;"""

# Extract info from master string
items = [s.strip().split('=') for s in master.split(';') if s]
keys = [item[0] for item in items]

# Process input lines, one at a time
for line in lines.splitlines():
    d = dict(items)
    new = dict(s.strip().split('=') for s in line.split(';') if s)
    d.update(new)
    for k in keys:
        print '%s=%s;' % (k, d[k]),
    print ""
```

This produces the output:

```
animals_goat=1; country=0 1 2; Foo=0 0 0; 
animals_goat=1; country=0 0 0; Foo=1 1 1;
```

Comment: I get the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dynamic_string search.py", line 51, in <module>
    new = dict(s.strip().split('=') for s in line.split(';') if s)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
>>>

Comment: @Doodle That says that the first section of the line was missing an `=` sign.  For example, `country; Foo=1 1 1;` would generate that error because there is no `=` sign following country.  Is this allowed in your input?  If so, what do you want to do when it happens?

Comment: Hi it is not missing the '=' sign. I printed it out at every stage. I will post the output shortly. Just that I cannot post the actual strings..

Comment: A quick question, I dont have the line sinside the ()... I see you have done that. Does it matter if I do not have it within () and just as a string??

Comment: Hi it works when I have it as (line) why is that? I created a variable with ('string1', 'string2') and that works...

Comment: @Doodle Yes, `lines` needs to be a tuple (or a list) so that, when the code `for line in lines:` runs, it pulls out a complete string not just a character.

Comment: Hi, When I try to do that, each line becomes a list I am following this, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630273/convert-multiline-into-list) I have this:  ['animals_goat=1;'' country=0 1 2;'' Foo=0 0 0;'] 
    ['animals_goat=1;'' country=0 0 0;'' Foo=1 1 1;']

Comment: @Doodle It is not clear to me exactly what you are doing.  Would you add the details in at the bottom of your question so I can have a look at it?

Comment: Thanks @john1024, it finally worked. I have a white space after ";" and that was considered an element and it was throwing me the same error. Now I got it to work by stripping it. You are cool thank you very much!!!