# How to convert a multiline string into a list of lines?

Tags: python, split, sikuli

In sikuli I've get a multiline string from clipboard like this...

```
Names = App.getClipboard();
```

So Name =

```
#corazona
#Pebleo00
#cofriasd
«paflio
```

and I have use this regex to delete the first character if it is not in x00-x7f hex range or is not a word, or is a digit

```
import re
Names = re.sub(r"(?m)^([^\x00-\x7F]+|\W|\d)", "", Names)
```

So now Names =

```
corazona
Pebleo00
cofriasd
paflio
```

But, I am having trouble with the second regex that converts "Names" into the items of a sequence. I would like to convert "Names" into...

```
'corazona', 'Pebleo00', 'cofriasd', 'paflio'
```

or

```
'corazona', 'Pebleo00', 'cofriasd', 'paflio',
```

So sikuli can then recognize it as a List (I've found that Sikuli is able to recognize it even with those last "comma" and "space" in the end) by using...

```
NamesAsList = eval(Names)
```

How could I do this in python? is it necessary to use regex, or there is other way to do this in python?

I have already done this but using .Net regex, I just don't know how to do it in python, I have googled it with no result.
This is how I did it using .Net regex

```
Text to find:
(.*[^$])(\r\n|\z)
Replace with:
'$1',%" "%
```

Thanks Advanced.

Comment: What about the first line?

Comment: Where goes the first line in the expected output? Why there is a comma at the last in your expected output?

Comment: Hi Avinash Raj, I edited my question to answer your questions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Multiline into list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630273/convert-multiline-into-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of one liners. Your question isn't completely clear - but I am assuming - you want to split a given string delimited by 'newline' and then generate a list of strings by removing the first character if it's not alpha numeric. Here's how I'd go about it

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]') # match @ beginning anything that's not alpha numeric 
s = '#abc\ndef\nghi'
l = [r.sub('', x) for x in s.split()]
# join this list with comma (if that's required else you got the list already)
','.join(l)
```

Hope that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If `Names` is a `string` before you "convert" it, in which each name is separated by a new line ('\n'), then this will work:

`NamesAsList = '\n'.split(Names)`

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630273/convert-multiline-into-list) for other options.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `splitlines()`

```
import re

clipBoard = App.getClipboard();
Names = re.sub(r"(?m)^([^\x00-\x7F]+|\W|\d)", "", clipBoard)
# Replace the end of a line with a comma. 
singleNames = ', '.join(Names.splitlines())
print(singleNames)
```