# Convert output printed on different lines into list python

Tags: python, list, output

I've been puzzling through this and can't seem to figure it out.

I have a large data set and have calculated some float objects, which prints each output in a new line when I print it (example subset of data below):

```
print(x)
> 1.22
> 1.33
> 1.44
```

I would like to convert these values to a list of strings:

```
['1.22','1.33','1.44']
```

I have tried converting the float objects to a string and following a similar suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630273/convert-multiline-into-list) and then trying to combine the lists using itertools.

```
x_in_list = [y for y in (i.strip() for i in str(x).splitlines()) if y]
x_combined = itertools.chain(*x_in_list)
```

Which gives me a lot of:

```
<itertools.chain object at 0x7ff6d00c2160>
<itertools.chain object at 0x7ff6e012f040>
<itertools.chain object at 0x7ff6d00c2250>
```

I think the problem has something to do with the fact I'm working with float objects here. I understand that I could probably do this in a simpler, more elegant way within my original loop, but now that I've started I'd really like to figure this out.

Comment: `itertools.chain(*x_in_list)` must be `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x_in_list)` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like `x` is a string with `\n` as delimiter. You can just use `split()` method of string to split `x` based on that delimiter.

You could simply do:

```
x_in_list = x.split()
```

By default `split()` splits the string based on whitespaces and newline characters.